# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) PYTHON tried several fixes

Tags: python

```
def login():
  username = input(" Voer uw gebruikersnaam in: ")
  password = input(" Voer uw wachtwoord in: ")
  auth = password.encode()
  auth_hash = hashlib.md5(auth).hexdigest()
with open("credentials.txt", "r") as inlog:
  stored_email, stored_pwd = inlog.read().split("\\n")
  inlog.close()
if username == stored_email and auth_hash == stored_pwd:
  print(" Succesvol ingelogd!" )
else:
  print(" Incorrect gebruikersnaam/wachtwoord! \\n")
```

Couldn't seem to figure out this code and error, have tried several fixes online but nothing seemed to have worked.

This is the little error that has been annoying me

> stored_email, stored_pwd = inlog.read().split("\n") ValueError: too
> many values to unpack (expected 2)

have tried looking for fixes online, nothing seemed to have worked unfortunately.

Comment: The file evidently contains more than one newline character, so the split produces more than two pieces.  I have no idea what's SUPPOSED to be in that file, so I can't suggest a fix.

Comment: would it help if I'd sent the full document?

Comment: Can you provide example of `credentials.txt`?

Comment: i don't have the actual file as its supposed to create this file when an account is being made

Answer (score 0):

Note that `inlog.read().split("\n")` will return list like this `['username','password']`. You need to convert it to a [tuple](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples.asp), so the output will be `('username','password')`. This output matches with the variable pattern `stored_email, stored_pwd`.

To solve your problem, you just change one line of your code. Instead use this :

```
stored_email, stored_pwd = inlog.read().split("\\n")
```

Try with this code :

```
stored_email, stored_pwd = tuple(inlog.read().split("\n"))
```

Comment: You don't need to convert to tuple as long as the list has exactly two elements.  The main problem was using `\\n` (two characters: escape code for a literal backslash and "n") instead of `\n` (one character: escape code for newline).

Comment: Hi i had entered the code and i thought it fixed it because it showed a new error message, after fixing this error the old one appeared again. Really odd, as I believe your solution should've fixed it.

Comment: What is new error message you got?

Comment: the new error message was just something about a space not being correct, am still receiving the same error message about the values

this is the current things that are in my credentials.txt when i try to log in still same error message
"pwinda
2094d2cdc870a13d3c3d250ac9973d46"

Comment: Please note that `2094d2cdc870a13d3c3d250ac9973d46` is the 32 chars of md5 decrypted / hash from your password. For example `md5("123")` will return `202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70`. [try this](https://www.md5online.org/md5-encrypt.html). Maybe you are getting that error because your password is wrong.

Comment: I know 100% sure that my password is correct as i copy a password enter it in the account creating and then copy it into the login agaij